# What could trigger an Inverse Chronological Order experience?

Tags: time-manipulation

In the movie "Memento", we as the viewer see the movie from what's called Inverse Chronological Order experience, where we see the ending first, and then the subsequent events leading up to the "beginning" of the story (which is not actually the beginning). This is because the character suffers from short term memory loss and cannot form new short term memory, so in order to emulate that, the story is tell using Inverse Chronological Order trope.

Is there any other situation where this situation can be triggered? Just an example I can think of, a brain scanner to find traumatic memory, so the doctor starts from the most recent memory, and then goes further back in the past memory.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/welcome-to-worldbuilding-se?noredirect=1) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour].  Please note that your question doesn't appear to be about the rules of a fictional world, but what circumstances would create the need to tell a story in reverse order.  In other words, you're not asking us how to develop a world, but how to tell a story.  You might want to try our [sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168).

Comment: Are you looking for reality-based answers? If so, tag this with `science-based`. If not, watch [The Arrival](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2543164/).

Comment: @Schwern I'm looking for a kinda reality-based answer. Something that feels like rooted in reality, but it's okay if stretched a little bit.

Comment: To me this looks like it's asking for brainstorming about story seeds. I don't see any criteria for what makes one answer better than another and it's basically the premise of every crime story: there is a murder and now you have to go backwards to find out what exactly happened. I am voting to temporarily put this question on hold as primarily opinion-based until it's been [edit]ed to add some criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Einstein-Rosen Bridge**

An Einstein-Rosen Bridge is a proposed theoretical wormhole that connects two different universes, where one is ours, and the other is ours, just mirrored. This includes the direction of time.

If your character moves through such a wormhole, ignoring the fact that the theory also suggests it'd be impossible to move through, the story would be in reverse chronological order, technically.

Comment: Ouw, that's an interesting one. Especially if the time also moves in paradox, like the character still experience life in forward, while all the other characters experience life in backwards. So at the first time he exits the wormhole, he's greeted by plethora of people who looks like knows him very well. As the time goes on, those people become less and less warm to him, up to a point where they're just met him, an acquaintance, while he's at the point where he knows them very well. After that, nobody knows him at all. That is interesting. Thanks!